# Import from CSV fails if there are more than one records in the csv file

Tags: sql, csv, cassandra, etl, nosql

Import from CSV fails if there are more than one records in the csv file, In this [sample file](https://www.evernote.com/shard/s308/sh/55d35f1a-3193-4174-8435-65f92762839e/9b84e27639d7a68cc1e00b1360eaa0fe), the data is delimited by single space ASCII value. Problem is every record has 'single space' even after the last column value, now when the system encounters this last 'single space' in each line .. its assuming as another column value and its not moving forward to the next record (as its unable to find the new line character).

Is there any to specify to ignore single space after last column value in each line?
Any way to consider this last single space on each line as newline character ?

I have thousands of rows so its impossible to manually replace last single space ASCII value with some end of line character?

On other note any good ETL tool which can help easily to move raw data into Cassandra to avoid above kind of problems?

**Error message**

```
$COPY sensors_data(samplenumber,magx,magy,magz,accx,accy,accz,gyror,gyrop,gyroy,lbutton,rbutton) FROM '/home/swift/cassandra/input-data/FallFromDesk1.csv' WITH DELIMITER=' ';
Record #0 (line 1) has the wrong number of fields (13 instead of 12).
```

**Note**
The above commands works perfectly if there is only 1 row in the .csv file or if we manually remove the single space after the last column value on each row.

Kindly help me out.

Comment: Create an additional column,import it,and then drop the column?

Comment: Thanks adding additional column did work, but this looks like a crude way to import data. Any good tool to easily import data into Cassandra ? Any ETL tool which helps in cleaning and formatting raw data which makes it easy to import data into Cassandra or other NoSQL databases?

Comment: Try Pentaho Data Integration. It reads from CSV files easily, allows you to specify what delimiter to use and has appliances to output into Cassandra. There's an open source Community Edition.